# Generate a sequence of timestamps by condition and an associated outcome in R

Tags: r, datetime, time, sequence, simulation

I want to get a sequence of timestamps down to seconds  starting at '2020-08-31 09:00:00' and ending at '2020-10-30 21:00:00'. I want to associate an outcome variable with it such that outcome is 100 for every 30 minutes and 1000 for the next 5 minutes then 100 for the next 30 minutes and so on. The system has a value of 100 for 30 minutes and 1000 for the next 5 and then 100 for 30 minutes again.

Thanks in advance

```
#Example OUTPUT

 TIMESTAMP                            OUTCOME
'2020-08-31 09:00:00'                 100   
'2020-08-31 09:30:00'                 1000
'2020-08-31 09:35:00'                 100
'2020-08-31 10:05:00'                 1000  
'2020-08-31 10:10:00'                 100  
'2020-08-31 10:40:00'                 1000
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create the vector of DateTime with `seq`

```
library(lubridate)
start <- as.POSIXct('2020-08-31 09:00:00')
timestamp <- c(start, start + minutes(cumsum(rep(c(30, 5), 2500))))
timestamp <- timestamp[timestamp <= '2020-10-30 21:00:00']
out <- data.frame(TIMESTAMP = timestamp,
    OUTCOME = rep(c(100, 1000), length.out = length(timestamp)))
head(out)
#            TIMESTAMP OUTCOME
#1 2020-08-31 09:00:00     100
#2 2020-08-31 09:30:00    1000
#3 2020-08-31 09:35:00     100
#4 2020-08-31 10:05:00    1000
#5 2020-08-31 10:10:00     100
#6 2020-08-31 10:40:00    1000
```

Comment: I think you could calculate the number of replications required exactly with something like `floor(as.numeric(end - start, units="mins") / (30 + 5))`

Comment: how do you get the 2500?

Comment: @HashingData it is just an arbitrary value.  You could use the method suggested by thelatemail to determine the length

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you